# Fastest way to update OpenGL VBO (including possibly expanding buffer)

Tags: python, opengl, vbo, pyopengl

I have a buffer that a user can update on runtime. The code works, however the window freezes noticeably whenever you update the buffer. I assume this is because of how I upload data to the buffer: I use `glBufferData` with `None` to clear the data, and then I use `glBufferSubData` to load the data to the buffer.
Note that the buffer can also increase in size.

So what is the fastest way to completely update a buffer and/or expand it's size? I know you can use `glMapBuffer`, however I am using Python so I am not familiar with pointers to memory space.

Comment: The question being about Python adds a wrinkle in that you're not able to do the kinds of trickery you can in more low-level languages (mapping, etc). And without that trickery, I don't know that there's a way to get good performance from these scenarios. It's possible that PyOpenGL has some abstraction around such trickery, but you'd have to look at its APIs to know.

Comment: Because most of the time I have to expand the buffer's size, so I can then send more data (because I need to render more faces) with `glBufferSubData`, which can only send data up to the buffer's maximum size.